# How to create solr cloud as a windows service

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper

We are using solr cloud as a search service and currently we run this from command prompt of windows, but I don't know how we can create solr cloud as a windows service on production environment.

I referred below document for the same,
http://www.norconex.com/how-to-run-solr5-as-a-service-on-windows/
but it is not working as expected for solr cloud.

Can anybody please help me on this.

Thanks,

Santosh

Answer (score 0):

You need to give some information on what is **not as expected** .

The link shown looks like it will get you some of the way, but you obviously need to run a couple of instances, give different home locations and probably setup dependencies between the services to ensure that the one with the Zookeeper starts first. All of which you should already have by running it on the command line, so you should only need to put the corresponding parameters into corresponding fields in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply, I was on vacation.

I can run solr cloud as a windows service , but for that I need to first ccreate a complete setup of solr cloud instance using command:
 solr -e cloud -z localhost:2181

then need to stop all the solr port running in command prompt , by closing the command prompt.

Then I configure individual windows service for each solr port running as below:

restart -c -f -p 8984 -z 0.0.0.0:2181 -s "C:/solr-5.2.1/example/cloud/node1/solr"

and so on for every port.

This way I can configure each solr running port as a windows service.

But I want to know , is there any command in solr cloud, which will create solr cloud setup as well run all solr port under single windows service instance.

the command like " solr -f -e cloud -z localhost:2181 -noprompt" , is doing that but it is running for only one default port i.e 8983, and I want to configure solr cloud setup for at least two ports just like "solr -e cloud -z localhost:2181 -noprompt" configured default in solr.cmd.

Thanks,

Santosh